# Are silicone polymers transparent to infrared light?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, material-science, infrared-radiation

I know that silicon and even black plastic bags are transparent to infrared light. What about light-colored silicone polymers (take white or green colors)? Are they transparent to infrared light too? And why?

Comment: Hi Mojiiz, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! I rephrased your question to improve the grammar. Please check and make sure this properly represents what you wanted to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silicone polymers are transparent. They do absorb some IR light (Google for examples) but they are only opaque if some filler has been added.

So whether or not any particular silicone polymers will transmit IR depends on what filler has been used in it. I think fillers tend to be aluminosilicates or metal oxides. Aluminosilicates transmit some IR light, but note that because the filler is a powder there will be a lot of scattering at particle boundaries so IR light is probably scattered by reflection just like visible light.

Comment: Today, I try to used IR camera (Thermal Camera) in normal light condition with "Silly Putty" (silicone polymer) result that it absorbs! ...

So, may be I will try with another filter. Thank you for your answer @JohnRennie If you have more suggestion please.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: In your suggestion mean that I need to use some filter (i.e aluminosilicates) cover IR light that projected to silicone polymer? then observe by NIR camera? right.

I should try. :) Thank you.

Comment: @MojiizAlamode: what are you trying to do? Maybe it would be worth asking a new question?

Comment: Sorry about that but I think that canbe continue question, actually I have a new question in [...here...](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/39624/which-viscoelastic-material-that-transparent-for-infrared-light) I would like to find the flexible dilatant material that pass the IR light, so that I can get the image same as using X-ray light.